# Cronjob immediately shuts down mac after boot

Tags: macos, terminal, cron, crontab

I was messing around with cronjob trying to get it to forcibly shut down at a certain time everyday, but now I can't keep my computer on. It boots, loads whatever needs to load on startup, then immediately forces a shut down.

I managed to pull up the cronjob quickly before it shut down and it looked "correct", meaning it should shutdown my computer at 3AM, but it is well past three and it immediately shuts down again.

I tried safe boot, but it just brings me to a login prompt where I can login as the user again, but it shuts down again.

I tried <kbd>Apple</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, did nothing. Tried logging in as guest, can't access anything. Tried Single User Mode, but everything seems to be read only. I need to get this turned on again so I can finish my work and catch my flight home in 12 hours, but I still have a lot of work to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Option 1) If you have another non-guest account, then try that.
Option 2)  If you have a second Mac of a laptop with a unix like OS and Firewire, try booting the mac in target disc mode and then access it from the other machine. (This will also work with windows computers with Firewire if you manage to get them to recognise the apple partition scheme and the filesystem. That is not quite as trivial with windows though).
Option 3)  Can you remount partitions are rw on OSX? (Something like `mount / -o remount rw`, change the cron files. sync sync sync reboot)

Comment: Apple-Option-P+R is known as "zapping the PRAM". It is similar to  restoring a PCs BIOS to the defaults. However your problem is not in booting. Your Mac successfully boots into OSX. Immediately after that it gets told to shut down (and does so). Trying to fix the already correct working boot process does not change that.

Comment: What I really want to know is: What is the cronjob that you wrote?

Comment: Aye. I guess it is something like "shutdown NOW: rather than a shutdown in a minute with a warning text "3AM. You should be sleeping. I know I (mac) will be asleep soon. Best save quickly"

Comment: The chron job was one that should shut the computer down at 5am every morning and the chron job "was" correct. I have no idea why or how it got stuck in the endless boot/shutdown cycle but the answer below helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boot again into single-user mode and execute the following:

`mount -uw /`

This command remounts your / partition in read-write mode as by default OS X is read-only when booted in single-user mode.

Make your changes, then reboot.

Comment: Done. Added a bit to say why it's read-only, too.